How to pass variable as table name in paws dynamodb batch_get_item?
I'd like to dynamically update the table name in batch_get_item. I see there are ways to do it in python and JSON, but is there a way to do so using paws in R?
For example, if I wanted to replace "Music" in the code below with "table_name", how would I do that?
svc$batch_get_item(
  RequestItems = list(
    Music = list(
      Keys = list(
        list(
          Artist = list(
            S = "No One You Know"
          ),
          SongTitle = list(
            S = "Call Me Today"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

I tried replacing the actual table name with "${table_name}" but received table not found errors (even though I can confirm the script works if I use the actual table name.) I also looked into Expression Attribute Names, but I am not familiar enough with paws to know how to use those effectively.
Thank you!
